# VB.NET, INFER ON and Enum.GetValues

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection, enumeration, type-inference

My project manager charged me to remove all "Option Infer On" directives from our solution (in order do not have undefined types, in his opinion).

```
Dim enums = [Enum].GetValues(enumType) ' here I will use "As Array" 

For Each item In enums ' <================== WHAT TYPE TO USE HERE?
  Dim ienum As [Enum] = CType(item, [Enum])

  Dim name As String
  Dim caption As String

  name = ienum.GetPropertyName
  caption = ienum.GetStringValue

  myDict.Add(caption, name)
Next item
```

Comment: For the record, when using `Option Infer` the types are NOT undefined. They are just not explicitly written in code. The compiler will still use an exact type. You can hover over the `Dim` keyword and Visual Studio will tell you what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx) it's an array of constants, so it will be an array of objects that you can cast to Integer.

FWIW I have got some code which does similar work, it picks up Attributes stored against each Enum value. For that I've used [GetNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames.aspx), then reflected back to the backing Enum field, to which I can search for Custom Attributes that store various bits of metadata such as "DisplayName" etc. Then the Enum can be reconstituted using `[Enum].Parse()`.

Hope that helps! Also, I think it's a dumb idea to have to change all your code because your manager doesn't trust the language/devs!

Answer (score 1):

The return type of GetValues is an Array of Objects. So the type of your "item" variable in the For Each loop will be Object.

Hope that helps.